# struct initialization fails with GCC 4

Tags: c, gcc-warning

I have a very weird issue whilst initializing a struct with GCC 4.5.3 on my x86_64 Linux box.

Code in question:

```
struct apr_finfo_t info = { 0 };
```

apr_finfo_t is quite some complex struct. I'll just say it has 17 complex other members.

```
struct apr_finfo_t {
    /** Allocates memory and closes lingering handles in the specified pool */
    apr_pool_t *pool;
    /** The bitmask describing valid fields of this apr_finfo_t structure 
     *  including all available 'wanted' fields and potentially more */
    apr_int32_t valid;
    /** The access permissions of the file.  Mimics Unix access rights. */
    apr_fileperms_t protection;
    /** The type of file.  One of APR_REG, APR_DIR, APR_CHR, APR_BLK, APR_PIPE, 
     * APR_LNK or APR_SOCK.  If the type is undetermined, the value is APR_NOFILE.
     * If the type cannot be determined, the value is APR_UNKFILE.
     */
    apr_filetype_e filetype;
    /** The user id that owns the file */
    apr_uid_t user;
    /** The group id that owns the file */
    apr_gid_t group;
    /** The inode of the file. */
    apr_ino_t inode;
    /** The id of the device the file is on. */
    apr_dev_t device;
    /** The number of hard links to the file. */
    apr_int32_t nlink;
    /** The size of the file */
    apr_off_t size;
    /** The storage size consumed by the file */
    apr_off_t csize;
    /** The time the file was last accessed */
    apr_time_t atime;
    /** The time the file was last modified */
    apr_time_t mtime;
    /** The time the file was created, or the inode was last changed */
    apr_time_t ctime;
    /** The pathname of the file (possibly unrooted) */
    const char *fname;
    /** The file's name (no path) in filesystem case */
    const char *name;
    /** The file's handle, if accessed (can be submitted to apr_duphandle) */
    struct apr_file_t *filehand;
};
```

Now, when compiling this piece with GCC 4.5.3 and **-std=c99 -pedantic -Wextra**, I'm seeing following warning message:

```
src/switch_apr.c: In function ‘switch_file_exists’:
src/switch_apr.c:518: warning: missing initializer
src/switch_apr.c:518: warning: (near initialization for ‘info.valid’)
```

Obviously GCC tries to initialize the first member, but already chokes on the second one.
This warning does NOT occur when not building with **-W** / **-Wextra**.

I **could** initialize each member by hand but that sounds weird and wrong.

From what I could gather from a Google search, it seems this initialization is perfectly legit and there are reports for GCC 3 where it works. Not with GCC 4.5 or 4.1 though.

Hope someone can help. :)

Best regards,

Mihai

Comment: don't you mean **-pedantic**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-Wextra` command-line option includes the `-Wmissing-field-initializers`.
Try adding `-Wno-missing-field-initializers` to your command-line.

```
$ cat 7724939.c 
#include <stdlib.h>

struct whatever {
  int a;
  int j;
  int k;
};

int main(void) {
  struct whatever x = {0};
  if (x.k) return EXIT_FAILURE;
  return 0;
}
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 4.6.1-4) 4.6.1
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ gcc -std=c99 -pedantic 7724939.c 
$ gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra 7724939.c 
7724939.c: In function ‘main’:
7724939.c:10:10: warning: missing initializer [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
7724939.c:10:10: warning: (near initialization for ‘x.j’) [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
$ gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers 7724939.c 
$
```

Note that the warning is not required by the C Standard. It's just your compiler trying to be (too) helpful.

Comment: Yeah, that's right as such (and also implied by me), but as GCC using -Werror actually *is* issuing some warning message I'm concerned all the other fields indeed don't get initialized. I can disable the warning just fine, but may only "mask" the problem.

Comment: With `{ 0 }` all fields get initialized with the correct type of `0`. See section 6.7.8/19 in the [C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf): "all subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized implicitly the same as bjects that have static storage duration."

Comment: So why does GCC claim they're n... oh, wait, it doesn't claim that. It claims you didn't specify initializers for all the other members (i.e. by hand), but it should still be inherited from the first one. Am I getting this right this time?

Comment: It doesn't inherit from the first one ... all fields not explicitly initialized get initialized to `0`. I like to call the `{0}` the universal zero initializer: it works for everything -- `int k = {0}; void *foo = {0}; char buffer[2000] = {0}; struct complicated stuff[42] = {0};` ...

Comment: If you do not use `0` in the list, only the corresponding fields get that value; all others get `0`. After `struct twoints { int a; int b; }; struct twoints x = {4};` you will have `x.a == 4;` and `x.b == 0;`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++ it would be much better to include a constructor that initialises, that way initialisation would only need to be written in the constructor instead of everywhere.

Comment: Sure, but that's obviously not my code and I won't rewrite APR in C++. ;)